# Deploying ASP.NET MVC to windows server 2003?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, deployment, iis-6, windows-server-2003

**Short Version**

I am a beginner program and my experience with launching programs is essentially hitting f5 in visual studio. How do I deploy an ASP.NET MVC app on a windows 2k3 server? When deployed, how would I access/run the site?

**Long Version:**

I am attempting to launch a simple ASP.NET MVC application to my company's win 2k3 server. I have included the binaries (for the MVC architecture, System.Web.Mvc, etc.) in my project as I am unsure if sp1 for ASP.NET 3.5 is installed.

I have absolutely no experience with server deployment, outside of deploying a simple ASP classic site on my localhost, so far I've been coding with the development server.

What is the process? When I click publish from Visual Studio, I select disk path and place it on my desktop, and then I transfer that folder to the server directory I want. The directory currently works with classic ASP pages, so I am placing my mvc app in a folder in that directory.

How do I access my site? I've tried \server\directory\MyMVCAppFolder\Home and several variations. (I changed my routing in Global.asax to account for .aspx extension, which is a nessecary evil dealing with win 2k3's IIS6)

In summation, how do I deploy a ASP.NET MVC site just having access to the server directory I wish to publish it, and how do I access it as an end user?

Comment: Here is a link explaining how to deploy MVC on IIS 6 http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/07/04/options-for-deploying-aspnet-mvc-to-iis-6/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read through this:

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx